# nested form in rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an error:

```
NoMethodError in Evaluations#new undefined method `evaluations_path' for 
  #<#<Class:0x007f99ddaea910>:0x007f99ddae88b8>
```

I have a nested form in:

```
def new
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @evaluation = @user.evaluations.build  
end
```

In view:

```
<%= form_with model: @evaluation, local: true do |f| %>
```

this line produces problem

Any idea?

My route file:

```
resources :users do 
  resources :evaluations 
end
```

Comment: Please show your routes file

Comment: resources :users do
    resources :evaluations
  end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the users to your form since is a nested route:

```
<%= form_with model: [@user, @evaluation], local: true do |f| %>
```

Comment: I used this but I after change this to a variable  user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @evaluation = user.evaluations.build

Comment: Do you still have the same error? `undefined method 'evaluations_path'`?

Comment: yes, the same error, a question, @evaluations in your model would be Evaluation.new

Comment: yes, it is plural... and appear undefined method `evaluations_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000006225578>:0x007f3d614062a8>

Comment: Are you talking about `@evaluation = @user.evaluations.build`? Because, `@evaluation` must be singular, but `evaluations` with out @ must be plural

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160873/discussion-between-s3tjan-and-alejandra-diaz).